# working of charindex,cross apply and substring in single query of sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a query as follows to display `@prodid= ''1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3''` from the string `'dbo.proudction @prodid= ''1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3'' ,@stock= 0'`:

```
declare @T table(Col1 varchar(100))
insert into @T values ('dbo.proudction @prodid= ''1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3'' ,@stock= 0')

select 
  substring(Col1, Start, Stop-Start)
from @T
  cross apply 
    (select charindex('''', Col1)+1) c1(Start)
  cross apply
    (select charindex('''', Col1, Start)) c2(Stop)
```

Can you help me to understand the working  of this query, please ?

Answer (score 0):

The first `cross apply` use [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) locate the first quote in the string. The second cross apply locates the second quote in the string. Then [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) will extract the text between the first quote and the second quote.

Result

```
1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3
```